# MySQL Data Statistics

Tags: c#, mysql, database, statistics

So, we have a table that basically includes most of the ticket details of a ticket, except for  stuff that is horribly long (like notes, tech notes, pictures, etc), those are linked elsewhere in other tables, etc.

We want to return metrics about the various tickets in the data table.  For example:

```
SELECT Category, Count(Category) FROM tickets 
WHERE Date_SUB(CURDATE(), Interval 16 Hour) <= Datez GROUP BY Category
```

Which would return a result listing, for example, each of our categories, and their counts.

However, if we want to adjust this for various intervals, like return the numbers for say `16 hours`, `1 day`, `30 day`, `3 month`, `12 month` and `All time`, are we going to have to run that same query that # of times (like for each of those listed minus all time, run that query 5 times?

Ultimately, we want to use the counts in a dashboard of some sort in our C# Winforms application, that will show us various ticket data, so we can see how the department is doing; but, if we have to sit there and run say 5 queries every few minutes, that can tend to bog down the system no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Category,
    IF(Date_SUB(CURDATE(), Interval 16 Hour) <= Datez, SUM(1), 0) AS c16hours,
    IF(Date_SUB(CURDATE(), Interval 1 day) <= Datez, SUM(1), 0) AS c1day,
    IF(Date_SUB(CURDATE(), Interval 30 days) <= Datez, SUM(1), 0) AS c30days,
    (...)
FROM tickets 
GROUP BY Category
```

This should work (but I have not tested the example, just giving you some theory)!

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Im sure you could add an AND statement as well after the WHERE statement, to continue the list.

This will def. shorten it up